# Slider invisible in vaadin

Tags: vaadin7

I am using a Vaadin Slider in a gridLayout but the slider is invisible, only the caption is there. This is my code:

```
GridLayout gridField = new GridLayout(2, 3);
gridField.setWidth(100.0f, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
gridField.setSpacing(true);
Slider slider=new Slider("name " ,0,100);
slider.setWidth(100.0f, Unit.PERCENTAGE);slider.setImmediate(true);
gridField.addComponent(slider);
```

Have you any idea please?

Comment: Simple `UI` & Vaadin 7.6.8 works as expected here. Can you share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to reproduce this?

Comment: I don't understand your comment Mr.Morfic

Comment: I'm saying that I created a simple implementation of a Vaadin `UI`, added the code you posted above, and everything works fine in Vaadin 7.6.8. Under the circumstances, it would be helpful if you could share with us a simple but complete example (also known as [sscce](http://sscce.org)) which reproduces your issue so we can have the necessary information to provide a valid solution. What you have shared so far seems to work fine and we can't really guess what's going on, thus a sample which reproduces this may reveal the actual problem.

Comment: In my theme I have this 
  .v-ui[width-range~="801px-"] {
    .valo-menu {
      @include animation(valo-animate-in-slide-right 700ms 700ms backwards);
    } used for another function ,it can be the probleme??

Comment: It doesn't look like it is this particular one, but if you override some defaults or define custom styles, they may change the appearance of your UI but unless you can share a sample which reproduces it we can't say for sure. Meanwhile, you can also try to see what DOM is being generated using developer tools: [chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), [firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), [ie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(v=vs.85).aspx), [edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/)

Comment: in Fact when I ignore theme slider work correctly but with my theme no.

Comment: then you need to identify which style is breaking your layout by either looking through your theme or using the developer tools inspector... Unfortunately, unless you share a [sscce](http://sscce) to reproduce the issue there's not much we can do to help you

Comment: I have this in my theme .v-ui[width-range~="801px-"] {
    .valo-menu {
     @include animation(valo-animate-in-slide-right 700ms 700ms backwards);
    }

Comment: Is that all of it? How did you define the theme? How are you applying it? Are you applying additional styles to the slider? etc... As I was saying, the simplest way to figure out what's happening is by sharing a sample project to reproduce the issue, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I have this in my theme $v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, slider);